# Recover deleted file despite full disk encryption

Tags: encryption

This might be a stupid question, but I'll go ahead and ask it anyway.

Say I am on Windows and I create a file, secret_financial_plan.txt, where I store all my company's black market financial operations. Once my operations are all finished, I delete the file and empty the recycle bin to cover my tracks.

A few days later I realize "permanently" deleted files in Windows are fairly easily recoverable. So, I decide to apply full disk encryption (FDE) on my device by switching over to Linux and using LUKS or by encrypting the drive in Windows with Veracrypt or by using some other piece of FDE-software. Would it be possible for a forensics expert, who does NOT have access to the decryption key, to recover the secret_financial_plan.txt file after having applied FDE, or not?

Comment: Possibly, unless you overwrite the entire disk with random data.

Comment: Possibly how? Assume the entire disk has not been overwritten with random data.

Comment: By outward appearances any properly implemented crypto scheme will be seemingly random data that can't be reversed without the encryption key. So essentially "Possibly, unless you overwrite the entire disk with random data." could be re-written as "No, unless you do encryption wrong."

Comment: @Fistbeard The file was not encrypted originally. I've never used Veracrypt, but with LUKS you'll be creating a new filesystem on top of the encrypted device, however the existing data won't be overwritten (except in a few spots like the LUKS header and the new filesystem data).

Comment: This is the kind of thing that ends up in news articles talking about how the criminal was looking for ways to cover their tracks prior to committing the crime.

Comment: @TotalFde Do you work for the likes of [Appleby](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2017/nov/05/offshore-law-firm-appleby-response-no-evidence-wrongdoing-paradise-papers)?

Comment: This is what one does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wp8sFsriH4c

Answer (score 43):

In addition to [Moshe's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/173216/151903), I'm going to provide an example with LUKS since some people seem unconvinced. Also, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71993/151903) for why overwriting may not be 100% effective (although it certainly helps).

### Example

Make a sparse file, create a filesystem, and mount it:

```
$ truncate -s 100G /tmp/device
$ mkfs.ext4 /tmp/device
$ sudo mount /tmp/device /mnt
$ sudo chown user:user -R /mnt
```

Make a few confidential files:

```
$ echo "super secret data" > /mnt/secret
$ echo "super secret data" > /mnt/confidential
$ echo "super secret data" > /mnt/top-secret
```

Get inodes for files:

```
$ ls -li /mnt
total 28
13 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    18 Nov 10 11:34 confidential
11 drwx------ 2 user user 16384 Nov 10 11:33 lost+found
12 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    18 Nov 10 11:34 secret
14 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    18 Nov 10 11:34 top-secret
```

Ensure files are written to disk, then get extents for inodes:

```
$ sync /mnt/*
$ debugfs -R "stat <12>" /tmp/device
...
EXTENTS:
(0):33793
$ debugfs -R "stat <13>" /tmp/device
...
EXTENTS:
(0):33794
$ debugfs -R "stat <14>" /tmp/device
...
EXTENTS:
(0):33795
```

Check those blocks to make sure the data is there:

```
$ dd if=/tmp/device bs=4096 skip=33793 count=1
super secret data
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 1.9034e-05 s, 215 MB/s
$ dd if=/tmp/device bs=4096 skip=33794 count=1
super secret data
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 1.888e-05 s, 217 MB/s
$ dd if=/tmp/device bs=4096 skip=33795 count=1
super secret data
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 7.1178e-05 s, 57.5 MB/s
```

Remove the files:

```
$ rm /mnt/secret
$ rm /mnt/confidential
$ rm /mnt/top-secret
$ ls -l /mnt
total 16
drwx------ 2 user user 16384 Nov 12 17:34 lost+found
```

Format the device using LUKS, then create a new filesystem:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /tmp/device

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /tmp/device irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase:
Verify passphrase:

$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /tmp/device encrypted_device
Enter passphrase for /tmp/device:

$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/encrypted_device
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Creating filesystem with 26213888 4k blocks and 6553600 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 279e6c3b-a183-4a94-b06e-78db1665b2a0
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Now we have a new filesystem:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/encrypted_device /mnt
$ sudo ls -lR /mnt
/mnt:
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Nov 10 11:37 lost+found

/mnt/lost+found:
total 0
```

But is our secret data still there?

```
$ dd if=/tmp/device bs=4096 skip=33793 count=1
super secret data
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 1.8944e-05 s, 216 MB/s
$ dd if=/tmp/device bs=4096 skip=33794 count=1
super secret data
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 2.2056e-05 s, 186 MB/s
$ dd if=/tmp/device bs=4096 skip=33795 count=1
super secret data
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 8.7082e-05 s, 47.0 MB/s
```

### Conclusion

Unless you wipe the disk, it's probable that at least some of the old data remains there unencrypted.

Comment: Conclusion : you don't do a full disk encryption.

Comment: @Whysmerhill Why you don't think this is full disk encryption? This is quite standard.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald, because by Whysmerhill's personal definition of full disk encryption, wiping the existing contents of the disk is a mandatory step in the process.

Comment: @Mark not at all. Wikiepedia definition : Expressions full disk encryption (FDE) or whole disk encryption signify that everything on disk is encrypted (except MBR..).
So if you use Bitlocker for example you will have to choose encrypt entire drive : https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/01/84.png to do FDE. If you do so your deleted file will be encrypted too.

Comment: This answers assumes that encryption software does not wipe the disk. The one I'm most familiar with, Truecrypt/Veracrypt, does offer to wipe the disk on creation of the encrypted volume.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The question asks about full disk encryption in general. Veracrypt may have the option to wipe the disk, but it can still be used without that option, and LUKS has no such option.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald The typical approach to wiping when setting up a LUKS container is to either (a) overwrite/TRIM/etc the underlying storage before creating the LUKS container (e.g. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/device bs=1M` in your case), or set up a separate mapping (usually dm-crypt not LUKS) with a temporary, throwaway key/passphrase, and fill *that* container from /dev/zero, before creating the LUKS container in its place. Some software (Ubuntu's installer is one example I know of) has a simple checkbox to do this, or you can do it yourself. TRIM once is often recommended on SSDs to reduce wear.

Comment: It is a best practice to fill the disk with random data before enabling FDE, but it may not be done by the solution used / it could be optional (sometimes within reason, such as when reinstalling over an already-random-filled disk).

Comment: @Whysmerhill, AndrolGenhald is storing the filesystem in a file instead of a hard disk for demonstrative purposes, *everything* on "that disk named /tmp/device" will be encrypted from now on. The problem is that the files that were stored in the old filesystem weren't. He is completely right. Thanks for taking the time of producing it!

Comment: @Ángel, No he misuses a tool and get erroneous conclusion to the asked question. If you encrypt everything, deleted files are included in everything. The OP 
 never say the original deleted file were on another disk. Use other tools that do FDE correctly like bitlocker (https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/01/84.png) and you will see that you can't recover the original deleted files.

Comment: @Whysmerhill : You have conflated "deleted files" with "whatever data happened to be on the disk prior to establishing an encrypted filesystem on it".  FDE does not change the contents of a block on the disk until writing new, encrypted data to that block.  Until overwriting writes occur, those blocks still contain whatever was last written to them via the unencrypted filesystem.

Comment: @Eric Towers, No FDE encrypt all the blocks present on the disk (with minor exception like MBR). So yes it will write a new block with encrypted value even if there is no "data" for the user point of view. It's written explicitly on the following picture: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/01/84.png. If LUKS doesn't do the same there is two possibilities: you don't use the correct option or LUKS doesn't do FDE.

Comment: When did you delete the file? You should have deleted the file before encrypting the disk

Comment: @ThomasWeller A fair point I suppose. It doesn't really change anything but I might as well add it in for completeness.

Comment: Truecrypt/Veracrypt warns you about this. When encrypting the disk it asks if you want to encrypt just the in-use blocks or the free space as well. In this case, you didn't encrypt the free space.

Comment: @Whysmerhill while I don't like specially the wording used by bitlocker in the screenshot you provide, it supports what is being argued here. The OP didn't specify the way that FDE was applied. If he chose the equivalent to the second option, that's fine and file won't be recoverable. If the OP chose the equivalent of the first one (not all FDE solutions support that), given that the file was deleted _prior to the FDE install_, it may be recoverable. AndrolGenhald example is a PoC of the second case. (And no, I didn't refer to a second disk, the _old filesystem_ was on the same disk)

Answer (score 25):

It comes down to the following question: Are the plaintext bytes of `secret_financial_plan.txt`'s contents still stored on the disk?

Let's go through the steps:

> I create a file, secret_financial_plan.txt, where I store all my company's black market financial operations

Plaintext is written to the disk

> I delete the file and empty the recycle bin to cover my tracks.

File is renamed and then the entry from the NTFS Master File Table is marked as deleted. The plaintext is still on the disk.

> I decide to apply full disk encryption (FDE) on my device by switching over to Linux and using LUKS or by encrypting the drive in Windows with Veracrypt or by using some other piece of FDE-software

There are different configuration options there. If you specified to encrypt the entire disk, including unallocated space, the plaintext bytes will be overwritten with the encrypted data. If you only encrypt the allocated space, the deleted file will not be overwritten* and so the plaintext *might* still be present, depending on whether or not it was overwritten by later writes to the disk.

<sub>* Note: These are the choices Bitlocker provides. I do not know how the other FDE tools operate.</sub>

Comment: So the "depending on whether or not it was overwritten by later writes" with lazy encryption is just the same situation as with the disk left unencrypted

Comment: Even if you encrypt the entire disk, it may still be possible to recover it using magnetic traces (assuming a magentic drive), correct?

Comment: @NathanMerrill, not if the drive was manufactured any time in the past quarter-century or so.  Reading residual magnetic traces stopped being viable sometime in the mid-1980s.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: You cannot be 100% sure that all traces are removed even if you overwrite the whole disk

Modern hard disks typically have more sectors than those that are displayed, especially SSDs for anti-wear-levelling reasons. Depending on the algorithm in the disk controller, it might decide that sector with the data of secret_financial_plan.txt will become a spare one and the data will be written to a previous spare sector.

Next point to take care of: copies might have been written to other location like temp files.

Next point: lets hope that it didn't get uploaded into the cloud. [Else your boss might get a call from his boss from the NSA that Isreal secret service reported them that they secretely hacked and watched a Russian antivirus vendor getting your super new secret spy virus uploaded through their cloud scanning technology because you used an virus infected crack for your pirated office suite.](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/oct/26/kaspersky-russia-nsa-contractor-leaked-us-hacking-tools-by-mistake-pirating-microsoft-office)

Comment: Not just temp files; the contents could be in a page file, too.

Comment: Note however that some modern disks implement the ATA Secure Erase standard, and can (assuming the manufacturer implemented it correctly) securely wipe all data from a disk, including anti-wear-levelling sectors.

Comment: @James_pic True, but I don't think it is done by default by FDE-software. As far as I can remember, it requires specialized tools from the drive manefacturer.

Comment: It doesn't require specialised tools from the drive manufacturer. It uses standard ATA commands, and can be done using hdparm on Linux. There is no technical reason why FDE software cannot support it.

Comment: good to know that it got standardized. I just remembered that every manufacturer distributed their own tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to recover the files after converting to FDE, but not guaranteed. The key thing is that FDE only provides protection after it is turned on. It doesn't protect anything before then. If the blocks on the drive were not overwritten (cryptographically) when converting to FDE then they are still there and can be recovered.
It is possible to wipe the drive before converting to FDE, but then it is the wipe that is making the previous data unaccessible, not the FDE.
And even then it is difficult to wipe a drive properly.

Answer (score 1):

Full disk encryption does not equate to overwriting the entire disk. Any data that wasn't wiped from the disk before encrypting will still be on the disk after it's encrypted. Think of setting up full disk encryption like formatting a disk: you write a few new blocks of data here and there but most of the disk remains untouched.

Comment: I don't think you can make a blanket statement like that, since different tools offer to encrypt the blank space, or not.  As we all learned in just the answers above.

Comment: "Blank space encryption" would typically refer to software that encrypts at the block level rather than the file level, and encrypts both used and unused blocks during use. This does not mean that the entire disk is overwritten during initial setup, and I cannot think of any encryption algorithm/protocol/standard/system that would involve overwriting the entire disk as part of the setup process. It's possible that some software offers this as an additional feature but that doesn't mean that "full disk encryption" involves overwriting the entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

The up-voted answers are all incomplete. The key question is if you encrypted the entire disk or if you just encrypted the parts that are in use.

When enabling full disk encryption you have a choice. You can encrypt just the parts of the disk that are in use by the filesystem. In that case, parts that are unused might contain deleted data and it will remain recoverable. This also leaks other information, such as approximately how much data the filesystem contains.

The other option is to encrypt even the free space, in which case even deleted files will not be recoverable.

Veracrypt/Truecrypt prompts you with this question when enabling FDE.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert, but my conclusion as an area of interest many years ago (before the SSD days) was that you cannot completely erase evidence of files on disk without destroying the disk itself.

Encrypting the desk after having deleted the file is a good step, but it may still be possible to recover the file, or parts of it, given sufficient tooling.

Consider a HDD which stores data as magnetic bit fields, on or off.  Let's say that piece of data is stored on that disk for some time, and then you come along and do (whatever) to your OS and encrypt everything and overwrite the disk 7 times with random data.  Great, right?  Except that it *still* may be possible to read the previous information from the disk, because at least on an HDD, if the data sits in place for long enough, the wear residue of the physical magnetic bits on the disk platter itself can still be read with highly advanced tooling.

Easy? no.  Possible? yes.

As with all things digital security related, I think it boils down to: how much effort do you think someone might put into trying to breach youre defenses (naturally balanced with how strong should your defenses be to thwart this)?  As with all things security related, the only way to ensure it will never, ever be breached is to make sure it never existed all.  My 2cents.

Comment: Data remnance on magnetic media hasn't been an issue for about a quarter-century.  These days, a single zero-wipe pass is enough to render the data unrecoverable even by magnetic-force microscopy.

Comment: @Mark - Quarter century? Sounds about when I last looked at it.  Thanks for the note.

Answer (score -3):

There are a whole bunch of theoretical attacks against whole disk encryption, but to my knowledge every single one of them involves capturing the encryption key when it is used, or exploiting a flaw in a specific encryption implementation. You explicitly specify that the attacker does not have your encryption key, so they will not be able to decrypt your data without another type of attack.

Comment: As specified in the question, the data was originally stored in the clear, and none of the subsequent steps is guaranteed to erase it.  The use of encryption is irrelevant in this situation.

Answer (score -4):

In windows, all you have to do is delete the file, then move data around using defrag or adding new files onto the drive.

Everytime you write data it sees the free space and overwrites it.
Alternatively, encrypt the drive BEFORE putting data on it, then do as you please?

Hope this helps.

Comment: _Moving data around_ may overwrite the secret file information… or not, using instead a different free spot.

Comment: This runs contrary to most information I've come across.  Can you elaborate and cite your sources, methods, etc?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser The described actions _might_ overwrite the file. Or Not. The answer assumes that the deleted file is the only free space on the drive. If there is more free space, some algorithm chooses which free space to use and which not. Doing the described actions just increases the chances to overwrite it, so you should avoid them if you want to recover the file to increase your chances to recover it. But doing them is not enough to make sure they are overwritten. Or just look at my answer for another example https://security.stackexchange.com/a/173241/94428

Comment: You're trying to give honor to your user name, don't you? Very silly approach.