# How far beyond using Shred should I go when deleting files?

Tags: hardware, data-leakage, deletion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-reliably-erase-all-information-on-a-hard-drive)

I'm looking to securely erase my files. Is [shred](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_shred.htm) the best option besides ditching the hardware? To what lengths should I reasonably expect to go to ensure my files are not recoverable?

Comment: I'm having difficult understanding your question. White flag? Throwing in the towel? With regards to what? In what situation are you using shred? What are your security requirements? Please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: I've edited the question with what I *think* you meant - if this is not what you meant to ask, please use the edit link to roll it back. Thanks.

Comment: You still need to give more information. What are your requirements? Are you an ordinary user trying to prevent script kiddies from getting your credit card numbers, or are you a member of anonymous looking to cover his tracks so when the FBI come knocking they'll hopefully get nothing?

Comment: @GregDolph Answering the latter may be incriminating... ;)

Comment: Curses, my cover's blown! Damn you Polynomial!! ;)

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using? A harddisk or flash/SSD? In the latter case, overwriting a file is not reliable, you need a specialized tool to clear the whole drive. And what file-system? I think there are some file systems where you can't simpyl delete single files.

Comment: I *know* this question has been asked before. I'm fairly certain I've answered it 3 or 4 times now.

Comment: @tylerl It's certainly been asked on SF and SU at some point. On Sec.SE, take your pick: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5749/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/11313/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5662/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/10464/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6133/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/11597/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/11188/5400 | http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7069/5400

Answer (score 0):

If you fear for the confidentiality of data, you should have used encryption, preferably full-disk encryption ([TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) has good repute). With encryption, you do not have to worry about the disk itself, only the key; destroying the key is as good as destroying the data. This makes the problem more manageable.

Assuming that you did not use encryption, and that you have a disk where a lot of very sensitive data has been written, and you want to destroy it beyond any recovery. Then you should destroy the disk itself. Don't shred the files, [shred the hardware](http://www.technologybloggers.org/computing/steps-to-take-before-throwing-away-your-old-pc/). You could employ other methods (melt the disk in a furnace, dissolve it in acid, wipe it with an EMP from a nuclear blast...) but the mechanical shredded is probably the safest to use in a home or small business ("safest" but not "safe": beware of trapping your hands in it !).

If the price of a new new disk makes you cringe and grit your teeth, then maybe the data is not really worth a lot ? Otherwise, there is no possible hesitation.

Comment: thank you, and as for the edit, I just started class yesterday and I'm taking 6 of them this semester, along side working to get CCNA cirt. This said, I was very tired. Thank you so much for the answers, and edits.