# Does full disk encryption securely remove data?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, data-recovery

I was just catching up on best practices for securely erasing data from a Mac. At one point I remember reading:

For SSD drives it is no longer recommended to fully write ones/zeroes/random bits on the disk. Use encryption instead.

Now, I am thinking of two starting points:

1. Your disk was not encrypted
2. Your disk was encrypted, but you are not sure if the new owner had the key

In both cases giving the laptop to the new owner would not be secure, deleting everything beforehand is a good step (and in practice strong enough for me personally) but I am not sure if that is sufficient.

Now my question:

**Suppose you have one of these two starting points, THEN you erase the drive normally and format it to be encrypted, are you then secure?**

The 'threat' I was worried about, is that the new owner would be able to format it back to the old way (e.g. without encryption, or with a specific encryption key) and it might be possible to use classical data retrieval techniques.

Perhaps it does not work like this (or it depends on the hardware), but I am hoping to understand if encryption of a disk means its previous contents can also not be retrieved anymore.

Comment: Encryption does not "remove" data

Comment: Data encryption has to be activated before you write sensitive data to the disk not after.

Comment: Related [Does formatting an SSD securely delete all data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/243795/86735) and [Wiping an SSD with Parted Magic seemed too quick](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/183286/86735)

Comment: @Robert It is only true for data encryption _external_ to storage device. Self-encrypting drives are always "encrypting" written data using a key which is kept internally. Effective encryption is activated just by setting a passphrase which is then used as a basis to encrypt the encryption key. So one can do that at any time, instantly switching a device which appeared unencrypted to encrypted state.

Answer (score 2):

If you store data on an SSD and *then* encrypt it, some unencrypted residue may still be present in the flash chips (it's not accessible through the normal storage protocol - SATA/SAS/NVMe/USB - though). The more the SSD is written to after encryption and the more completely it is filled, the smaller that residue gets.

The exact amount depends on the flash controller's wear-leveling algorithm and the (spare) capacity of the SSD. Most often, you don't know much about that and can only guess.

So no, you're not entirely secure encrypting an SSD *after* sensitive data has been written to it without encryption.

Usually, you encrypt a drive right after installation and only then do you write sensitive data to it.

Some drives have a *secure erase* feature that allows you to kill *all* data at a low level.

And of course, if you want to *erase a disk* (HDD or SSD), all blocks need to be overwritten (multiple times for SSD as outlined above, one time for HDD is sufficient). Deleting files, quick formating, or deleting a partition all don't really remove data from the drive and can largely be undone.

Comment: There is another potential problem: When you activate encryption usually only used sectors are encrypted (unless configured otherwise, not sure about encryption on Mac). This means the sectors not being overwritten can be more than just the spare sectors currently not mapped to a logical sector.

Comment: @Robert Good point - whether the whole drive is (pre)encrypted or just the used space depends on the actual implementation (*block level* vs. *filesystem level* encryption may make a difference).

Comment: Even a block level encryption can initially just encrypt the used disk space. Most file-systems have a free/used bit mask or something similar so it is easy to limit encryption to the used blocks.

Comment: A *filesystem-agnostic* block-level encryption needs to encrypt the whole disk, but there are many different approaches.

Comment: It's not possible to access the "spare" part of the SSD disk using normal methods, so a single overwrite is enough for more intents and purposes.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It's not (usually) possible via the flash controller, but it's certainly possible by accessing the flash memory chips directly.

Comment: And again, this can be done by the OEM only using very expensive equipment. Let's remain sensible and stop asking people to do illogical things because they feel reasonable to you. They aren't or otherwise you'd operate with facts and provide links.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That isn't expensive at all - flash controlling circuitry is easy and cheap to get.

Comment: Facts, links, studies, please. Cases when people's data has been extracted from the spare area or I'll call this BS. This is a technology website, not "trust me bro" website. I still remember when people argued you needed to overwrite HDD multiple times to securely erase data and then **no one** had ever provided a single case when data from the overwritten HDD was extracted and then NSA or FBI (don't remember now) admitted they had never been able to do that either. And then you **believe** the data in this spare area is stored as is. You do **not** know it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov For instance, see https://www.tomshardware.com/picturestory/655-ssd-flash-recovery-2.html - while that shows a professional service, all important steps can be done at home with more effort. Not easy, but certainly not too expensive.

Comment: The necessity for multiple overwrites of HDDs was based on a study by Peter Gutmann in 1996 for then-obsolete technology (MFM/RLL). It was pretty obsolete from the beginning but got stuck in many heads.

Comment: This article is 8 years old and talks about flash which indeed could be read by certain equipment. Modern SSDs however are a whole different beast altogether. Again, I've not seen a single story where anything has been recovered after simple `cat /dev/zero > /dev/nvme0n1`