# Completely wiping a HDD (i.e. nothing is recoverable)

Tags: tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-reliably-erase-all-information-on-a-hard-drive)

I'm looking to see if there's a method that can completely wipe out the content of a HDD, so that nothing previously on it can be recovered by any means, even by a professional. I'd like the HDD to be useable afterward by someone else.

I've come across HDDGuru, File Shredder, and DBAN.. As I understand them, they write on the HDD over and over to make recovery difficult at the minimum. How effective are these? DBAN seems the most promising..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero out all the data if the drive is magnetic.

The DoD 5220.22-M specification requires 3 passes, though I personally go for 7 each time.

-> [Related Gizmodo article](http://gizmodo.com/5494427/leave-no-trace-how-to-completely-erase-your-hard-drives-ssds-and-thumb-drives)

Answer (score 4):

**The best way to erase a magnetic hard drive** ([not SSDs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/is-it-enough-to-only-wipe-a-flash-drive-once)) while leaving the drive working is [the ATA Secure Erase command](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-reliably-erase-all-information-on-a-hard-drive).

For a single use of this, a (relatively) simple'ish way of accessing a compatible, modern tool which implements ATA Secure Erase is:

- Download and run [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB stick.
- Download [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) or a similar special Linux distro oriented towards disk tools. (Using other Linux disk images will probably also work.) Install the disk image to the USB key using UNetbooting.
- Boot from the USB key, and enter a Linux command line. From here, perform the [secure erase with HDParm](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/articles/a/t/a/ATA_Secure_Erase_936d.html).

Good end user tools for ATA Secure Erase are unfortunately a bit hard to come by. I don't know of anything much easier than the above.

If the above software isn't working for you, then just use a single wipe pass from conventional software that overwrites the drive with random data. That's still [good enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/5824/2122). Such software for example be found on the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com).

Comment: I recall reading a test where a shockingly large percentage of drive's firmware would accept the secure erase command, but basically so nothing. It was a NO-OP that returned no error. Much safer to do a single-pass random data overwrite with DBAN, and it takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt a sledgehammer, a blast furnace, or thermite does the trick.

Comment: "I'd like the HDD to be useable afterward by someone else." It will be reusable but only as a paperweight or doorstop.

Answer (score 2):

DBAN is great.  I know first hand that it is used in big corporations and in recycling shops.