# Is a single reset sufficient to make data irrecoverable?

Tags: android

I have a Samsung A13 with the latest version of Android OS. Does one pass of factory reset make all data irrecoverable, or do I have to make multiple passes?

Answer (score 4):

Your phone is encrypted by default, so unless an attacker has your password or your master key isn't erased (it is likely that it is) in the reset, it will be virtually impossible to recover the data.

More thorough info is available in the accepted answer to this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84060/what-really-happens-during-a-factory-reset-does-it-securely-erase-all-data

Comment: Note that, in theory, a single overwrite of a flash cell may not always be sufficient to prevent recovery: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/245435/106285